# Facebook PHP SDK token issue: "An active access token must be used to query information about the current user."

Tags: php, facebook, facebook-graph-api, oauth

I've spent a good deal of time trying to find my solution in previous questions on this site but haven't been able to.

The first time my user authenticates, the process works fine. But when they return the second time they get the exception: "OAuthException: An active access token must be used to query information about the current user."

I thought the SDK handled tokens at a lower level so that I didn't need to deal with them?

```
    $app_id     = "XXXXXXXXXXXXXXX";
$app_secret = "XXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXX";
$site_url   = "http://domain.com/";   

try{
    include_once "src/facebook.php";
}catch(Exception $e){
    error_log($e);
}

$facebook = new Facebook(array(
    'appId'     => $app_id,
    'secret'    => $app_secret,
    'cookie' => true
    ));

$user = $facebook->getUser();

if ($user) {
  try {
    // Proceed knowing you have a logged in user who's authenticated.
    $user_profile = $facebook->api('/me');
  } catch (FacebookApiException $e) {
    error_log($e);
    $user = null;
  }
}


if ($user) {
  $logoutUrl = $facebook->getLogoutUrl();
} else {
  $loginUrl = $facebook->getLoginUrl(array(
        'scope'         => 'read_stream, email, user_about_me, user_photos',
        'redirect_uri'  => $site_url,
        ));
}
try {
    $albums = $facebook->api('/'.($_GET['fbuser'] ? $_GET['fbuser'] : 'me').'/albums');
} catch (FacebookApiException $e) {
    print $e;
    $user = null;
}

$access_token = $facebook->getAccessToken();

foreach($albums['data'] as $album):
[...]
```

Comment: Is it happening as soon as you navigate to the page in question? Or is it happening when user navigates to the page after an hour or so?

Comment: on the second or 3rd time. as in they dont have to log into facebook this time. is it because im not passing a token in future sessions?

Comment: Most probably your token, the one you are getting here is a short lived token and due to that when user visits second time, the token has already expired. Try using long lived token instead.